# How to sort on a field and only return the first row per grouping?

Tags: linux, sorting

If I have a file, like this:

```
1,blue
2,red
3,green
13,blue
5,green
1,red
```

I want to sort everything by the second column and only return the first line.

So my output would be:

```
13,blue
5,green
2,red
```

cat file.txt | sort -k1n ...

Comment: How do you select among the same values in the second column? It seems you used the max in column 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to select the maximal value in the column 1 for each value in the column 2.

```
sort -t, -k2,2 -k1,1nr file | sort -su -t, -k2,2
```

The first sorts the file by the second column (`-k2,2`), sorting the lines with the same value in the second column by the values in the first column (`-k1,1`) numerically (`n`) in a reverse order (`r`). Then another sort is run, this time with `-u` for unique, i.e. only one line will be preserved for each value in the second column. The `-s` means a stable sort, this should keep the first line of each group, i.e. the maximum.